# What makes it possible to get argument from different method?

Tags: python

If I run this script, it returns an error `NameError: name 'args' is not defined`.

```python
import argparse

def no_args():
  print(f"no_args: args is {args.arg1}") # error here

def with_args(args):
  print(f"with_args: args is {args}")

def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--arg1")
  args = parser.parse_args()
  
  with_args(args.arg1)
  no_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

However, when I move the logic in `main()` to under `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause, it works fine, both `no_args` and `with_args(args)` return same output.

```python
import argparse

def no_args():
  print(f"no_args: args is {args.arg1}")

def with_args(args):
  print(f"with_args: args is {args}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("--arg1")
  args = parser.parse_args()
  
  with_args(args.arg1)
  no_args()
```

```
❯ python arg.py --arg1 apple
with_args: args is apple
no_args: args is apple
```

What mechanism of Python makes it possible to access command-line arguments from the method without passing it as an argument? Entire methods in the same file can access variables in global space (not sure what it's called)? If so, which is the defacto standard if I want to use command-line arguments from multiple methods?

- set an argument to each method and pass it from `main()`
- use it globally without creating `main()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Python's variable scope, which is slightly different from other languages like Java, C++.

Python variables are scoped to the function, class, or module in which they're assigned, but control blocks like `if` and `while` blocks do not have scopes.

Therefore, `args` inside `if __name__ == "__main__"`can be accessed by other functions. However, `args` inside `def main()` cannot.